Users are getting Access Denied if they try to access th site without specifying the home page name
I have a communication online sharepoint site, and i defined some users to have access (Read-Only) to only the home page nothing else. now the users can access the home page using this full url (by specifying the page name inside the url):-
https://*.sharepoint.com/sites/SalesHub/SitePages/TopicHome.aspx
but if they try to access the site url only :-
https://*.sharepoint.com/sites/SalesHub/
They will get Access Denied, as follow:-

although the TopicHome is the home page of the site.. any advice?

I have done tests in lots of site collections and tenants. This behavior is expected and is not a cause for concern.
When a user accesses the site, except the home page, he also accesses some site settings, such as site navigation, site theme and etc.
When a user accesses the home page through URL, he only accesses a page, not including site navigation, site theme and etc.
So, in the SharePoint online, if a user is able to view the home page only, the user will not automatically get limited-access permission on the site collection, he cannot access the site.

so you mean accessing the home page using the site url only (without specifying the page name), cannot be done for users who only have access to the home page? the limited-access will not have any effect?
